# Failure to Include system.web.http in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently trying to unit test an `ApiController` I've created.
What I'm stumbling over is that for some reason I can't "use" `System.Web.Http`. In my main project though I can use the `using` without any problem (and thus use `IHttpActionResult`).

Now what I'm not getting is why is it not possible in the unit test Project? Am I overlooking here something or do I need to do something differently?

Comment: Sorry for asking something trivial, but did you reference System.Web in your project?

Comment: @FrancescoB. I know ist mostly the trivial things thus that was the first Thing I did. I even went so far that I included most Sub references then (also.entity,... ) which the main application had, but no visible effect (sadly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2096814.aspx?), `System.Web.Http` can be installed via NuGet

```
Get-Project MyTestProject | Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
```

I tested it in my Unit Test Project and it worked, actually downloading it. [image: System.Web.Http].

After all, the `System.Web` namespace doesn't seem to contain any `Http` member.

Anyway, since you said in the comments section that you already had `System.Web.Http` in your references, off the top of my head I'd say that maybe some dependencies were missing before installing the NuGet package.

`WebApi.Core` depends on

- `WebApi.Client` (see [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/)), which in turn depends on
- `Newtonsoft.Json` (see [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/))

A very, very similar question was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819109/system-web-http-missing-after-net-4-5-upgrade).

Comment: Yeah that worked. Although have to ask....WHY? (the System.web.http dll was even in the packages from the start but it still only worked after doíng the install).  Is there any known reason as to why this is the case?

Comment: My guess is you were missing some other dependency, I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: ah tnx that would be a possibility (newtonsoft I know I had already as I used JObjects   webapi.Client I'm not sure about if the Project had included).   tnx!